# How to pass zmq context (void *) properly?

Tags: c++, c, zeromq, void-pointers

I am using zmq's native C library to write my application (the application itself is written in C++ though). The ZMQ version is 4.04. The problem I have is that I have a factory class which provides singleton access to zmq context, which is a void pointer created by `zmq_ctx_new ()`. The zmq context itself is stored as a static member variable and a getter method is provided to access reference to this variable. The class itself is quite simple, here is the complete code:

**zmq_ctx_factory.h**

```
#include <zmq.h>
#include <cassert>

class ZmqCtxFactory
{
public:
  static void* get_ctx()
  {
    assert (zmq_ctx_ != (void*) NULL);
    return &zmq_ctx_;
  }

  static bool is_initialized()
  {
    return is_initialized_;
  }

  static void init()
  {
    zmq_ctx_ = zmq_ctx_new ();
    is_initialized_ = true;
  }
private:
  static void* zmq_ctx_;
  static bool is_initialized_;
};
```

**zmq_ctx_factory.cpp**

```
#include "zmq_ctx_factory.h"

bool ZmqCtxFactory::is_initialized_ = false;
void* ZmqCtxFactory::zmq_ctx_ = NULL;
```

Here comes the question, in my client code, below would give an error (error code 14, Bad Address)

```
void* context = ZmqCtxFactory::get_ctx();
assert (context != (void*) NULL);
socket_ = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_SUB);
```

but if I replace `ZmqCtxFactory::get_ctx();` with `zmq_ctx_new ();`, the code works fine. As you can see, I have an assertion to make sure the context is not NULL, that means the ctx variable is created successfully. (as per the document, if the creation failed, `zmq_ctx_new ()` returns NULL). I am confused, why the reference returned by the factory wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ZmqCtxFactory::get_ctx()` seems to return *the address* of the pointer, not the pointer itself.

Try

```
static void* get_ctx()
{
    assert (zmq_ctx_ != (void*) NULL);
    return zmq_ctx_; // instead of return &zmq_ctx_;
}
```

Comment: I figured out the same thing right after I posted it, will accept your answer in 7 min. :)

Comment: After I posted, I re-read your question and wanted to add a remark about returning by reference. But at that time you answered the question already :).

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that `static void* get_ctx()` doesn't return a reference, it returns address of the void pointer. After changing the method to below the code works fine:

```
static void*& get_ctx()
  {
    assert (zmq_ctx_ != (void*) NULL);
    return zmq_ctx_;
  }
```